# .Net version needed

Tags: .net, installation

I want to know what the prerequisites are for my application. One is the installed .Net version. How can I know the minimum .NET number necessary to run my application.

I use Visual Studio 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Properties of your project, then [**Publish -> Prerequisites**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y%28VS.80%29.aspx). There will be a list of all possible prerequisites. Yours will be checked.

Answer (score 3):

You can view the version of .NET your application uses (and also change it) in the Project Properties window (Project menu > MyProject properties). Examine the Target Framework dropdown to see which version of the framework your application uses.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2005 compiles for .NET 2.0

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to your Project Properties page, on the "Publish" tab use the "Application files" button to view all the prerequisites your application needs, this will include third party components and other dependencies too.

The "References" page shows the list of dependencies too, use the "Unused references" button to remove any unused ones.